# Bitwise operators for filtering?

Tags: python, django, database-design, architecture, bit-manipulation

I am struggling a little bit to find a nice data representation for a fairly typical scheduling app. The requirements which mess things up a bit is that there are two parties each who have an arbitrary availability daily and there are courses which are offered more or less at fixed times (though exceptions can occur here as well) independent of whether there are two parties available at that timing or not.

As one of the challenges later will be to find available providers for the scheduled courses, I was wondering whether a quick and elegant way could be to simply store a weekly availability pattern for these in a 64-bit integer with a kind of bit-mask.

My rationale is that essentially, every day has 24 hours (< 2^5) and splitting the day into 10 minute intervals there are 144 slots per day (much less than 2^8). Therefore, every person could get a weekly schedule with every day being an 8 bit availability mask for that day (7 x 8bit = 56 bit, less than a 64 bit int).

Filtering and identifying of potential users can very quickly and simply be done by converting any potential appointments into the same kind of mask and then just doing a bitwise operation to only select candidates which are available there without bothering about further rules etc.

What I am wondering is what the reasons are why I don't see much more filtering happening on bit-level as it seems to be fairly straight forward and I'm guessing will hopefully actually even end up being more elegant than a more verbose and explicit logic, any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: Uhm wouldn't 144 slots be a 144 bit mask, 1 bit to signal each slot available or not? In an 8bit number you'd only be capable of saying, User is available in the 100th slot for 10 minutes. You could use an 8 bit mask where each bit is an available hour in the "normal" 8 hour workday though. But not in 144 slots. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good point and I feel very stupid for missing that ;-) Actually, in this case though even the 8 bit mask would probably be sufficient. Overall, I am quite intrigued by using this kind of masking for quick filtering and I haven't really seen this being done in any of the web projects I've seen so I'm wondering what the reason is (or if I'm just looking at the wrong projects...) so the original question still has high relevance to me...

Answer (score 3):

Typical case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Get your program running first, and only if it is slow, you should start thinking about optimizing it with bitwise operations. You should really start with implementing it in the cleanest way possible, for example by using a vector or list of booleans, which are not limited to some arbitrary length of 64.

You could use for example a `numpy` array with `dtype=bool`. This might be slightly less compact than a hand-coded bit-vector, but you get all [logical operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) for free (you can also use operators like `|, ^, & and ~`), and on top you can have virtually unlimited size, allow for slicing, indexing, etc.

Comment: On the one hand intuitively I would agree - but on the other hand this actually came to my mind based on simple elegance. If you just use a long list of booleans or a vector I am not sure how you would be able to simply ensure all edge cases with availability being interrupted in the middle of the period etc. - all this in a bitwise operation would actually be taken care of "for free" - you just create one simple library which takes a start and end time and day and translates to a bitwise pattern which you compare bit for bit.

Comment: @Jonas what edge cases? I do not see any case that you can solve with 64-bit integers that you cannot do with a list/array of booleans. And why waste time on writing your own library, when all functionality is already available in standard python or in very common external libraries like numpy. That is exactly the premature optimization thing: you might save a few seconds by using fast bitwise operations, but meanwhile you have spent a week on implementing and debugging your library, if you finish at all. Unless you do this for fun, of course, then you can do whatever you want ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels I might have not understood your solution correctly. So you mean essentially instead of using e.g. 11001111 as an 8-bit integer I take a bool array with 8 elements? If I have an appointment which is 00000111 (i.e. the first three time slots) then I just create another bool array for that and use logical_and to see if that schedule has availability there? Sounds like it could work.

Comment: There is however the extra issue of saving this schedule information in the database now (project is web-based using Django) - I could of course use something like cPickle but then would have to deserialize all entries every time I filter which seems quite expensive given that there probably will be at least a few thousand such availability schedules and this is a very frequent operation or am I missing something?